# Unit of measure for NV_ENC_PIC_PARAMS.inputDuration

Tags: nvenc

What should I put into `NV_ENC_PIC_PARAMS.inputDuration`? According to the documentation `inputTimeStamp` can be any monotonically growing value, but I am struggling to find anything on `inputDuration`.

Should it just be `frame.inputTimeStamp - prevFrame.inputTimeStamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever unit you choose, it doesn't impact the encoding process at all.

`NV_ENC_PIC_PARAMS` `inputTimeStamp` and `inputDuration` are copied to `NV_ENC_LOCK_BITSTREAM` `outputTimeStamp` and `outputDuration` respectively to keep track which picture produced which bitstream.

The `inputTimeStamp` can be additionally used to invalidate reference frames with `NvEncInvalidateRefFrames`.